# Jquery internal ajax (get) not working on phonegap + android 2.2

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, mobile

I don't know for sure if the problem is in the request or in the display of the results, but this is not working for me, when I tap on the link on the phone I get a white screen, on desktop (Chrome) works without problems.

```
$('a').on('click', function(click_event){
  $.get($(this).attr('href'),function(response_text){
    $('body').html(response_text)           
 })
 click_event.preventDefault()
 return false
})
```

'Debugging' with weinre it tells me it enters on the get function...
I'm using PhoneGap Build and have not set a config.xml, but when I install the app on the phone, it ask permission to access to the Internet...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the last parameter 'dataType' as 'html' on the get call, for some reason it was assuming another type of content (xml or json I guess). Everything is working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL within the href?

Is it an external URL or a local path?

If the latter, read in to the Whitelist Guide here...

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide